# DataSet to XML file in legacy ASP.NET Web Forms application

Tags: c#, asp.net

I'm trying to identify a legacy ASP.NET Web Forms web application project as "code first" or "database first" (or "model first"). My observations are:

- Entity Framework is not being used
- a SQL database is accessed for a DataSet, which is then written out to an XML file (which is used as the data source)
- there are .cs classes identifying the structure of the target data display (table rows etc)
- XmlDataSource is not being used

EDIT:
The project appears to be an XML-file-as-database project, but based on a SQL database; with the ability to rewrite the XML database by re-querying a the SQL database.

I find this two-step a little odd, and so I am wondering if this is common for ASP.NET web applications, and what the possible advantages of handling data this way are.

Comment: What kind of answer do you want to get?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Microsoft defines a [DataSet](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.dataset?view=xamarinios-10.8) (in part) like this:

> The DataSet, which is an in-memory cache of data retrieved from a data source, is a major component of the ADO.NET architecture. The DataSet consists of a collection of DataTable objects that you can relate to each other with DataRelation objects.

From my experience, and as near as I can tell from the docs, a DataSet cannot be used in a code-first approach, as it does not have the same capabilities as Entity Framework. As to the XML:

> A DataSet can read and write data and schema as XML documents. The data and schema can then be transported across HTTP and used by any application, on any platform that is XML-enabled.

XML (along with the associated C# classes) is the typical format of a DataSet in a Visual Studio project. Following the advent of Entity Framework, DataSets are no longer the recommended method for accessing data in an ASP.NET project (or any other .NET project for that matter).

Comment: Ah, that explains it--thank you! So it likely is a Database first project template with XML database I'm guessing then. Or was there a different project type for that convention? (I'm looking for a tutorial for this kind of project)

Comment: You will likely have to dig back into some old .NET 2.0 docs for that tutorial. It _is_ a database-first approach, but more primitive than EF. Instead of dbContexts and objects, you have to deal with TableAdapters that load data from the database into DataTable objects.